# Autosort not working anymore: Google spreadsheet

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a working script on an old version of a Google spreadsheet that isn't working any more.
It was a sorting script which sorts out the rows each time one or more column is modified.

On the new spreadsheet that isn't working any more. I'm trying to figure out why but I can't catch where the error is.

Can anyone help?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  Logger.clear()
  Logger.log('Script Start')
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  Logger.log('ss=%s', ss)
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  Logger.log('sheet=%s',sheet)

  Logger.log('SheetName=%s',sheet.getName())
  if(sheet.getName()=='MembriForum'){
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  Logger.log('editedCell=%s', editedCell)
  } 

  var columnToSortBy_1 = 4;
  var columnToSortBy_2 = 6;
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  Logger.log('range=%s', range)


  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy_1 || editedCell.getColumn() ==     columnToSortBy_2){   
    var range = sheet.getRange(range.getRow()+1,         range.getColumn(),range.getNumRows()-1,range.getNumColumns() );
    Logger.log('range=%s', range)
     range.sort([{ column: columnToSortBy_1, ascending: true }, { column:     columnToSortBy_2, ascending: true}]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is unfortunately due to an [issue in new spreadsheets](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3496)...

See [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3496) for details and star it to (hopefully) get more attention from Google.

Your condition will never be true since `editedCell.getColumn()` will always be `1`.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed confirm on the answer. Regards